# Accessing Child class Object from Another Child Class without creating new object in cpp

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have a scenario where I need to access an object of a child class from another child class
I have something like this:
In **parent.h**

```
#include "child1.h"
#include "child2.h"

class Parent
{
public:

    Child1 Child1_obj;
    Child2 Child2_obj;

    void setVar2_Value(int v2)
    {
        Child2_obj.Var2 = v2;
    }
};
```

In **child1.h**

```
#include "child2.h"
class Child1
{
private:
    int Var1;
public:

    // these below functions are in .cpp file but I am placing here for simplicity to post
    int DoArithmetic()
    {
       int temp1 = Increment_and_Multiply();
       return temp1;
    }
    int Increment_and_Multiply()
    {
        Child2* pChild2;               // How to initialize so I can access the value of the same object created inside Class A, insted of pointing to new Child2 object
        
        // first increment Var2 and then multiply. I want this increment to be reflected  in object created in class A
        pChild2->Var2++;
        return pChild2->Var2 * Var1;
    }
};
```

In **child2.h**

```
#include "Child1.h"
class Child2
{
public:
    int Var2; 
};
```

In **main.cpp**

```
#include "parent.h"
int main()
{
    Parent P1;
    P1.setVar2_Value(5);            // set Var2 value to 5
    int res = P1.Child1_obj.DoArithmetic();
                                    // Var2 value in now 6
    // Do something else                                

}
```

As mentioned in the comments, I want Child2 class object access from Child1 so I can directly modify its values from Child1 which also get reflected in the object created in the parent class. Any guidance on this will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There is no special relationship between member variables and the object - if any - of which they are members - what do you expect to happen if you write `int main() { Child1 c; c.Increment_and_Multiply(); }`? You need to arrange any such relationship yourself. (And being a member is not usually what is meant by "child class"; that refers to inheritance, not composition.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, these are not logically parent and child classes but I just named these to explain my question better. Any help on how to correct my logic to achieve what I am trying to do ?

Comment: They are just member variables, and they have no knowledge of either each other or where they are kept. You need to make `Child1_obj` aware of `Child2_obj`, for instance by handing it a pointer on construction. Exactly like if they were not members of a third object.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference to the child when you need access to it. Rather than calling `Child1::DoArithmetic` let the caller call `Parent::Arithmetic`:

```
class Child2
{
public:
    int Var2; 
};

class Child1
{
private:
    int Var1;
public:


    // these below functions are in .cpp file but I am placing here for simplicity to post
    int DoArithmetic(Child2& child2)
    {
       int temp1 = Increment_and_Multiply(child2);
       return temp1;
    }
    int Increment_and_Multiply(Child2& child2)
    {
        // first increment Var2 and then multiply. I want this increment to be reflected  in object created in class A
        child2.Var2++;
        return child2.Var2 * Var1;
    }
};


class Parent
{
public:
    Child1 Child1_obj;
    Child2 Child2_obj;
    int DoArithmetic() {
        return Child1_obj.DoArithmetic(Child2_obj);
    }
    void setVar2_Value(int v2)
    {
        Child2_obj.Var2 = v2;
    }
}; 

int main()
{
    Parent P1;
    P1.setVar2_Value(5);            // set Var2 value to 5
    int res = P1.DoArithmetic();
                                    // Var2 value in now 6
    // Do something else                                

}
```

PS: Do not define default constructors that do nothing. If you want to declare them then do `Child1() = default;`. There is also no need to declare the constructor when the compiler can geenrate it for you.